# AJAX concepts in zend framework

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I am new to using the Zend framework. Please give me information on how to integrate AJAX concepts with Zend, and try to give one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework is a PHP framework and it doesn't force you to integrate AJAX in any special way. You can use AJAX like you normally do with javascript.